# Android listView implementaion with different layouts for a single row

Tags: android, listview

I have a listView implemented with adapter holders and object..

For a single item of the listView,
there are three different things to be shown..

The first is the summary..(one xml)(one view)
After that a dynamic number of layouts is to be shown having a specified xml layout.

After that a layout showing 2 buttons

How to implement this...

please help

Attached is this screenshot
this is one row of listView...

[image]

Comment: please post what you have already tried

Comment: You can use a `RelativeLayout` as parent view, and as childs put the summary layout at the top, the buttons layout at bottom and your list in between.

Comment: If i put a list in between, it gives problem because then it becomes a listview inside a listview... I want multiple rows like this.. In image, its a single row of listView